# Missing argument 1 when injecting parameter in formtype

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-forms

Here my service definition :
services.yml:

```
petapp.form.type.species:
class: PetAppCoreBundle\Form\Type\SpeciesType
arguments: ['%locale%']
tags:
- { name: form.type }
```

In config.yml

```
parameters:
locale: en
```

In my Species Type :

```
/**
* Default locale
*
* @var sting
*
*/
private $default_locale;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param string $locale
 */
public function __construct($locale)
{
    $this->default_locale = $locale;
}
```

I don't undertstand why the DIC does not call my FormType with %locale% parameter.
I have the following error :

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for PetApp\CoreBundle\Form\Type\SpeciesType::__construct(), called in /home/dev/petapp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php on line 90 and defined
```

I call createForm with new 2.8 syntax: (php 5.4)

```
$form = $this->createForm('PetApp\CoreBundle\Form\Type\SpeciesType',$species);
```

Do you have any idea about this issue ?
Thanks.

David

Comment: Are you sure your `services.yml` file is imported in `config.yml`? See the tip block in http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service

Comment: You can use `php app/console debug:container` to check if your form is actually registered as a service after checking that the config file is actually loaded. By the way: Does the `services.yml` really look like in your question (the `services` key is missing and indentation is broken)?

Comment: [dev@goliath petapp]$ console debug:container | grep species
  petapp.form.type.species                                             PetAppCoreBundle\Form\Type\SpeciesType

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
$form = $this->createForm(SpeciesType:class,$species);
```

instead of:

```
$form = $this->createForm('PetApp\CoreBundle\Form\Type\SpeciesType',$species);
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers

@Yassine Guedidi :

My service seems correctly registered in container :
    [dev@goliath petapp]$ console debug:container | grep species
     petapp.form.type.species    PetAppCoreBundle\Form\Type\SpeciesType

@xabbuh :
in service.yml of CoreBundle:

```
services:
    petapp.form.type.species:
        class: PetAppCoreBundle\Form\Type\SpeciesType
        arguments:
            - 'en'
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

@Matteo :
This syntax is only for 5.5.
    $form = $this->createForm(SpeciesType:class,$species);

Answer (score 0):

@xabbuh. Thanks, there was a typo error on FQCN.

PetApp\CoreBundle\Form\Type\SpeciesType instead of PetAppCoreBundle\Form\Type\SpeciesType

```
  petapp.form.type.species:
    class: PetApp\CoreBundle\Form\Type\SpeciesType
    arguments: ['%locale%']
    tags:
    - { name: form.type }
```